# Setting up a test database in Django

Tags: postgresql, session, django-testing

I want to create integration tests so that i can create 1000 records of a single model in my database.

for my settings.py file i have specified to use the same database `default` when running tests.

```
if 'test' in sys.argv or 'test_coverage' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'TableName',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': 'postgres',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': 'password',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '5432',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        }
    }
```

When i run the command `python manage.py test <app>` i get an error stating that i have two sessions running.

```
 Got an error creating the test database: source database "template1" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 1 other session(s) using the database.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `python manage.py runserver` or any other processes accessing your postgresql (such as pgadmin3 or phppgadmin) is disabled before running your tests.

In other words, make sure that you have killed the running **postgresql connections for your application**.

You can also determine which are the open connections that an application is making to your postgresql database via

```
psql -U postgres

postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

and if you want to be specific, you can do:-

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity where datname = 'TaleeboBixin';
```

Comment: The database test are created and destroyed, if i create records, does this mean they will be deleted when the test is completed?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. A new db named `test_TaleeboBixin` (because your actual database is named `TaleeboBixin`) will be created for you. and this db will be deleted when the test run completes.

Comment: I really want to create test of models that don't go away, what are my options then if this test dB goes away?

Comment: Yes you can write a custom test runner that persists your test models. Here's an example - http://packages.python.org/django-test-utils/keep_database_runner.html